# SCSS Mixin append ::before styling

Tags: css, sass, mixins

```css
@mixin item {
  /* Element Styling */
  ::before {
    /* Element ::Before Styling */
  }
  :hover::before {
    /* Hover animation to be performed by the before when the main element is in a hover state */
  }
}

.item {
  @include item;
}
```

This SCSS example produces the following in CSS

```css
.item {
   /* Element Styling */
 }
  item ::before {
    /* Element ::Before Styling */
  }
  item :hover::before {
    /* Hover animation to be performed by the before when the main element is in a hover state */
  }
```

Because of the nature of how mixins work, it adds a space between `item` and `::before` which causes those to not be associated with each other in the manner that is expected. When this space is removed the element behaves as expected.

How would I go about using the same or similar method to achive the following output?

```css
.item {
   /* Element Styling */
 }
  item::before {
    /* Element ::Before Styling */
  }
  item:hover::before {
    /* Hover animation to be performed by the before when the main element is in a hover state */
  }
```

If you can't tell what the difference is, `item ::before` is now `item::before` and so on...

Comment: Oh man @Nit,
Just a bit too late to answer. Right after Oriol.

Comment: This is a duplicate but I could not find that question due to its title and the question and answer are not as strait forward. Normally the shorter the better as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&`:

> [**Referencing Parent Selectors: `&`**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)
>
> Sometimes it’s useful to use a nested rule’s parent selector in other
>   ways than the default. [...] In these cases, you can explicitly
>   specify where the parent selector should be inserted using the `&`
>   character.

```
@mixin item {
  /* Element Styling */
  &::before {
    /* Element ::Before Styling */
  }
  &:hover::before {
    /* Hover animation to be performed by the before when the main element is in a hover state */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the ampersand:

```
@mixin item {
  /* Element Styling */
  &::before {
    /* Element ::Before Styling */
  }
  &:hover::before {
    /* Hover animation to be performed by the before when the main element is in a hover state */
  }
}

.item {
  @include item;
}
```